# Flutter: How to show hindi character in my app?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, i am using API to fetch data and it responds with a string containing Hindi character. But when I printed the `response.body` it shows as following (gibberish)

[image]

Now same is shown on my emulator screen but if I copy pasted the Hindi text and render then it works:

[image]

Code snippet of both scenario i.e in title data from API response and in body same string copy pasted( and working as expected):

```
ListTile(
                        dense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        title: Text(
                          data['testVersion']['name'] != null
                              ? data['testVersion']['name']
                              : 'NA',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'NatoSansDevnagri',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        trailing: Text(data['testVersion']['time'] != null
                            ? data['testVersion']['time']
                            : 'NA'),
                      ),
                      Text('Below string is copy pasted in text widget from swagger response'),
                      Text(
                      ( 'इस पेपर में 150 वस्तुनिष्ठ बहुविकल्पीय प्रश्न हैं। यह प्रश्न पुस्तिका निम्नलिखित पांच खंडों से बनी है: धारा- I, 11, 111, IV और 30-30 प्रश्न प्रत्येक। उम्मीदवार को सभी वर्गों का प्रयास करना होगा। प्रत्येक प्रश्न एक अंक का है। गलत उत्तर के लिए कोई नकारात्मक अंकन नहीं है'),
                      ),
```

So, please help me how is it not working from api response ?

Thanks

Comment: that i did, as you can see the response is used in the app `data['testVersion']['name']` but same gibberish font shown, but when I directly copy-pasted it, then it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dart is probably decoding the server response body in charset Latin-1 (instead of utf-8). You can specify the encoding as :

```
http.Response response = await http.get('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
var responseJson = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

print(responseJson) // This should print Hindi characters in the Terminal
```

Comment: For me works this only:  utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)